# Tell Browser to use dark color scheme?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

if i open up 9gag on Chrome on my phone, the menu bar changes its color to a dark theme, but when i go to for example ebay.com, it switches back to white. How can i achieve this? How can my website tell Chrome "hey, please use dark mode for this page"?

Googling was not successful, as i do not know how to phrase this correctly - i only found blogposts describing how to activate dark mode as user, but i want my website to tell the browser to be dark, if thats possible

Thanks in Advance,
stay healthy

Comment: Maybe browser takes average color of page?

Comment: hm my page is black BG with some white text, and also my example 9gag is not in dark mode or anything - its mostly white

Comment: Have you tried solutions from this site: https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/change-your-websites-address-bar-to-your-brand-colors/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: Thanks Justinas that was exactly what i was looking for! now my black website uses matching black menu bars :)

Comment: @Justinas if you post your comment as an answer i would love to mark it as solution :)